# Can one call an instance's method inside a class without recreating the instance within class' scope?

Tags: php, oop, scope

I'm relatively new to PHP, I'm trying to make a script to log errors from try/catch blocks.  I've run into a scope problem trying to do so.

First, I attempted to make the class instance a global variable but that didn't work.

I know it is possible to make a new instance each time 'AnotherClass' is called; however, that would clear the '$errors' array in 'errorhandler'.

I've been stuck on this issue for a few hours and any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php

class errorhandler
{
    private $errors = [];
    function log($e = '')
    {
        print "Opps! An error occured: " . $e;
        array_push($this->errors, $e);
    }
}

# global $errorhandler; # Doesn't work...
$errorhandler = new errorhandler();

class AnotherClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $not_possible = 1/0;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $errorhandler->log($e); # Doesn't work
        }
    }
}

new AnotherClass();

?>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the global `$errorhandler` variable into your local scope:

```
class AnotherClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        global $errorhandler;

        try {
            $not_possible = 1/0;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $errorhandler->log($e); # Doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** `1/0` is not an exception, it's a runtime error. You can't catch those with a `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: But DONT do that. Inject the error handler into the class via the constructor or some other method. Additionally, in this specific instance you should be using [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: Ok! Wouldn't have thought of that, but that idea makes sense